# Check ArrayList for instance of object

Tags: java, arraylist, instanceof

I have a java method that should check through an ArrayList and check if it contains an instance of a given class. I need to pass the method the type of class to check for as a parameter, and if the List contains an object of the given type, then return it.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public static <T> T find(Collection<?> arrayList, Class<T> clazz)
{
    for(Object o : arrayList)
    {
        if (o != null && o.getClass() == clazz)
        {
            return clazz.cast(o);
        }
    }

    return null;    
}
```

and call

```
String match = find(myArrayList, String.class);
```

Comment: You need to use `Class.isAssignableFrom` to handle subclasses, also the method should take `Collection` instead of `ArrayList` (ie, program to the interface). Also consider using Java's recommended coding standard of making method names start with lowercase.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: or `Class.isInstance`

Answer (score 5):

```
public static <T> T getFirstElementOfTypeIn( List<?> list, Class<T> clazz )
{
  for ( Object o : list )
  {
    if ( clazz.isAssignableFrom( o.getClass() ) )
    {
      return clazz.cast( o );
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: `clazz.isAssignableFrom( o.getClass() )` can be written as `clazz.isInstance( o )`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 you can do:

```
public <T> Optional<T> getInstanceOf(Class<T> clazz, Collection<?> collection) {
    return (Optional<T>) collection.stream()
            .filter(e -> clazz.isInstance(e.getClass()))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Check the documentation of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) if you never used it before. Actually this is better practice than [returning null](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#optional).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterator over your list and test each element

```
Class<?> zz = String.class;
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (zz.isInstance(obj)) {
        System.out.println("Yes it is a string");
    }
}
```

Note that `isInstance` also captures subclasses. Otherwise see Bela`s answer.

Comment: This has been down voted, but seems to be the better solution where you are unconcerned with subclasses of the class or subclass you're checking; as in my case, and as the post explains. So why the down vote? If no good explanation can be given, I'm up voting.

Answer (score 0):

check one of the the item instance in the list

```
if (object instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
                        if (((ArrayList<?>) object).get(0) instanceof ClassA) {
                            classAList= (ArrayList<ClassA>) object;
                        } else if (((ArrayList<?>) object).get(0) instanceof ClassB) {
                            classBList= (ArrayList<classB>) object;
                        } else if (((ArrayList<?>) object).get(0) instanceof ClassC) {
                            classCList= (ArrayList<ClassC>) object;
                        }
                    }
```