# How to test if a certain object is inside a list

Tags: java

Im adding a POJO to a linked list and now I want to check if the list contains that object. The code below does not work, any suggestions?

```
List<Object> data = new LinkedList<Object>();

FooBar obj = new FooBar();

data.add(obj);

if (data.contains(FooBar.class)) {
    // true
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to see if `data` contains the object `obj`, or are you trying to tell if it contains any object of type `FooBar`?

Comment: if the list contains an object of type FooBar

Comment: In that case refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350158/check-arraylist-for-instance-of-object

Comment: @Purpl3Paul, for this case, I updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if (data.contains(obj)) {
    // true
}
```

?

The method [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) for a List will only return `true` if, for any element in the list, is true that `element.equals(parameter)`.

**EDIT:** If you're trying to test is there is any instance of `FooBar` in your list and you're using Java 8, you can do:

```
if (strs.stream().anyMatch(e -> e instanceof FooBar)) {
    // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to do `data.contains(obj)` i.e. pass actual object for comparison.

ArrayList `implements` the List Interface. If you look at the [Javadoc for `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) at the `contains` method you will see that it uses the `equals()` method to evaluate if two objects are the same.

Hence to make this work, you need to override `equals` method like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 ..
}
```

Comment: What if i'm creating the object in another class, and adding the object to a list in said class. The parent class will receive the list and then will need to test that the object is in the list. How would i test that?

Comment: @Purpl3Paul In every scenario you will surely have object of FooBar to be used for comparison which can be used. How you are going to compare without object?

Comment: This was to check if specific object is present. To check if any object of specified class is present refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350158/check-arraylist-for-instance-of-object

Comment: If i create and instantiate a simple object in a sub class and add the object to a list in the sub class and then return the list to the parent class, how can i test if the list returned has an instance of the simple object. Im not creating any simple object in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the equals method in the POJO object.

The if you just do contains it would always return false, because the object will never be equal. So you will have to override the POJO object.

You can look at this question on how to override an equals method :
[How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

For more look at :
http://crunchify.com/how-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-method-in-java/